# Modelo Entidade Relacionamento: Ternário vs Agregação?

Tags: sql, modelagem

Supondo que eu tenha um relacionamento ternário: duas entidades entre si são NxN e a terceira entidade é fraca em relação ao relacionamento entre essas duas.

Gostaria de saber a diferença entre criar uma agregação entre as duas entidades NxN e deixar sem a agregação e o que cada uma das duas opções causa do banco de dados, se possível dizendo as vantagens e desvantagens.

Comment: Mostre exemplos que você quer comparar, se possível:

Answer (score 2):

Existe uma ligeira diferença nas abordagens MER e UML, acredito que pela sua pergunta esses conceitos estão um pouco confusos.

## Notação MER x UML

Na modelagem Entidade Relacionamento (MER) existe o relacionamento ternário que é composto por entidades independentes entre si (esse ternário é meio complicado) observe os exemplos.

No livro é possível ver alguns exemplos de relacionamentos ternários, veja:

### Exemplo 1

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Exemplo 2

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### Perceba que no contexto do **MER** é possível existir:

Um ternário com 2 entidades fortes gerando um entidade filha ou fraca [exemplo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ob5pV.png)

Um ternário com 3 entidades fortes (não gera entidade filha ou fraca) [exemplo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwGh4.png)

Imagino que não existe 1 entidade forte gerando 2 entidades fracas

### Unified Modeling Language - UML

A UML introduz o conceito de classe(Entidade) e o termo associação(relacionamento) entre classes. A associação pode ser desmembrada em 2 tipos, são eles: agregação e composição

[Nesse link: exemplo de agregação](http://www.ateomomento.com.br/uml-classes-agregacao/) eu encontrei uma explicação bem fácil sobre os tipos de associação, o artigo do link explica bem a diferença entre agregação e composição, que são tipos de associação.

### Respondendo as perguntas

Se duas entidades possuem uma relação M:N e você não cria a terceira entidade para guardar os atributos chaves das entidades fortes, então você vai causar uma duplicação de registro desnecessária no seu banco, pois quando você estiver implementando o SQL do seu projeto lógico, a chave primária da tabela A vai ter que aparecer na tabela B e vice versa.

Fonte: Sistemas de Banco de dados 6ª edição, autores: Elmasri, Ramez Navathe, Shamkant B. Ano: 2011, pg 131.